# resque no longer starts "Can't assign requested address - connect(2)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, connection, redis, ruby-on-rails-3.2, resque

**Since a few days I'm unable to start resque I have tried debugging this issue on all kinds of ways to no result ! anyone knows a solution? kind regards**

This is the log output from:

```
 bundle exec rake resque:start
```

log:

```
bundle exec rake resque:start --trace
** Invoke resque:start (first_time)
** Invoke resque:workers:start (first_time)
** Execute resque:workers:start
rake aborted!
Can't assign requested address - connect(2)

Tasks: TOP => resque:work
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
*** Starting worker dev2.local:4323:critical,high,low
** [09:01:12 2012-06-15] 4323: Registered signals
** Invoke resque:scheduler:start (first_time)
** Execute resque:scheduler:start
rake aborted!
Can't assign requested address - connect(2)

Tasks: TOP => resque:scheduler
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
2012-06-15 21:01:20 Schedule empty! Set Resque.schedule
** Invoke resque:web:start (first_time)
** Execute resque:web:start
/Users/jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:346:in `open_http': 500 Internal Server Error (OpenURI::HTTPError)
```

I tried:

- downgrading redis
- upgrading redis
- downgrading resque + upgrading resque to latest version again
- reset all config files and try again
- all ports are default just default config
- checked if the default ports where closed
- looked true the resque gem code trying to figure out where exactly it happens

Im totally halted because Resque is integral part of my app, please anyone who knows solution let me know.

Comment: Did you check if any other application is using the port? On Linux you can do it for example with `netstat -tlnp | grep 4323` (preferably as a root).

Comment: development on OSX yes the port is free. the 4323 is the PID of the process. The default port of redis not sure out of head what it is ,is used.

Comment: Generally this kind of error rise when their is one local server address is used by two applications.

Comment: @chs thx but I really have 1 ruby on rails app running locally

Comment: Out of curiosity, you don't happen to have Resque mounted in your routes file... do you?

Comment: Yes I have it routed in my routes but that made no problem before. Already tried to disable it   mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"
made no difference

Comment: Seems like when I create a clean app it does work.. :S Now only in my app I get an error on startup: :public is no longer used to avoid overloading Module#public, use :public_folder instead
 from /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/resque-1.8.2/lib/resque/server.rb:11:in `<class:Server>'

Comment: For your class:Server error, it looks like it's an incompatibility between resque 1.8.2 and newer versions on redis.  check this link out [link] (http://www.kensodev.com/2011/08/31/rails-uninitialized-constant-resqueserver/)

Comment: @Rubytastic i don't think my previous comment actually applies to you.   I'm not sure if the warning actually causes any errors, in any case, it appears to be fixed in [the 1.20.0 version](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/480#issuecomment-4053950) of the gem.  Can't help on the resque error, but I was getting the 500 resque-web error after manually killing a resque-web process.  Shutting down and rebooting fixed resque-web for me (OSX 10.7.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

It seems that, it looks like it's an incompatibility between resque 1.8.2 and newer versions on red is. Like @bknoles suggested.

Using

```
gem 'resque', "~> 1.20.0"
gem 'resque-scheduler', :require => 'resque_scheduler'
```

In gemfile fixes the problem

Comment: It generates conflict: resque 1.20.0 need redis < 3.0.0 and newest resque-scheduler - redis 3.0.1